# Get all related users that don't relate to a certain relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 tables which are users table, rule table, rule_requests table and rule_employee table. Find the tables below.

User table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | test1 |
| 12 | test2 |
| 13 | test3 |

Rule

| id | active |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |
| 2 | true |

rule requests

| rule_id | request_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Normal leave |
| 2 | Sick leave |

rule employee table

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 12 |

Each user may have a rule and each rule must have at least 1 request type. What I want to do is to get all users that don't have a certain request type rule. For example, if I want all users that don't have **'sick leave'** request type rule, I should get 10 and 13.
What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: You'd use a SELECT query with a JOIN and perhaps a subquery ; but the exact syntax depends on what kind of database system you're using and the exact names of the tables & fields

Comment: Could you specify PK and FK in the table? Where is the link between rule and employee?

Answer (score 3):

I noticed you put this question in Laravel tag, so in Laravel answer would be..
Model User and Rule will have a pivot relationship by `belongsToMany` relation

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then Call User Model Such as..

```
$filter_role_id = 2; // id of sick leave
$location_other_listings = User::whereDoesntHave([
        'roles' => function($query) use ($filter_role_id){
            $query->where('id', $filter_role_id);
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

This should get all  User Without that specific role